# Assembly, relying on registers vs variables for efficiency?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I've come across a lot of situations where I'm using all registers and need to save a value temporarily and don't know whether to declare a new variable or juggle the registers and the stack to somehow accommodate the value somewhere (eg: using PUSHA and POPA to store everything on the stack temporarily).

In some cases it's simple but in others the code becomes needlessly long for not adding an extra variable.

Is there some sort of drawback with using variables instead of registers? How do you choose which to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is known as register scheduling and is a large part of the problems languages like C solve for you.

Registers are faster than RAM. If you can use a register instead of a memory location that is preferable. However calculations spilling out into memory is inevitable.

Depending on the assembler you are using you may be able to name memory locations on the stack. For example if you are using [MASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masm) then you can use the [LOCAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5xh578d.aspx) directive to give variables on the stack a symbolic name. If you need anything more than the most ephemeral of temporary storage then you should find a way to name it. In a year you will not remember what you put in [ESI+12]. PUSH and POP can still be your friend. For example I used to like to use PUSH and POP to do a memory to memory move or to save a pointer when inserting or removing a node in a linked list.

If you need something to persist for the entire execution of your program then using a variable is the only way to go. Remember global variables are evil (even if necessary) in every language.